# "Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property" with Spring 3

Tags: java, spring

I'm upgrading an old project from Spring from 2.0.7 to 3.1.1. After this change when we try to deploy the .ear (JBoss 4.3 cp09) we're getting an error message:

> Error creating bean with name 'com.xxx.xxx.Bean2#193eb05' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through bean property 'map2': : Error creating bean with name 'bean1': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bean1': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireByType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1199)

This is (part of) the applicationContex.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans default-autowire="autodetect">
    <bean id="bean1" class="com.xxx.xxx.Bean1">
        <constructor-arg index="0">
            <list>
                <bean class="com.xxx.xxx.Bean2" />
                <bean class="com.xxx.xxx.Bean3" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This is (part of) Bean2.java

```java
public class Bean2 extends Class2{
    // .....
}
```

This is (part of) Class2.java

```java
public class Class2 {
   // ...

   private Map<String, Object> map2;

   public final Map<String, Object> getMap2() {
        return this.map2;
   }

   public final void setMap2(Map<String, Object> map2) {
        this.map2 = map2;
    }
}
```

We have some problem with the map `map2`. Unfortunately I can't change the value of the default-autowire property.

Comment: The `Map<String, ?>` is a special case of auto wiring in newer spring versions, it will give you the beans of the given type. However as you are using a `Map<String, Object>` it is going to give you all the beans leading to a circulair dependency.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is inject a regular Map (not one containing Spring beans) I suggest you take a look at `javax.annotation.Resource` which is supported in Spring for cases